# Mapping two columns based on common/key column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have two sheets as shown below

This sheet provides a mapping between type and product

| Type | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Xmas_Green | Xmas Tree |
| Xmas_Red | Xmas Tree |
| Xmas_Blue | Xmas Tree |
| Bunny_Red | Bunny |
| Bunny_Blue | Bunny |

and the another sheet provides mapping between products and vendor as shown below

| Product | Vendor |
| --- | --- |
| Xmas Tree | Xmas Corp Ltd |
| Bunny | Bunny Corp Ltd |

Using the above sheets, I want to generate another sheet showing type to vendor mapping (based on product)

| Type | Vendor |
| --- | --- |
| Xmas_Green | Xmas Corp Ltd |
| Xmas_Red | Xmas Corp Ltd |
| Xmas_Blue | Xmas Corp Ltd |
| Bunny_Red | Bunny Corp Ltd |
| Bunny_Blue | Bunny Corp Ltd |

So far I have tried to use VSLOOKUP to match tables based on column but it expects 1:1 mapping to work. Another approach I'm trying is to count duplicates on `Product` and duplicate the `Vendor` based on `Product` count. This needs to scale up for 6000+ records and VBA macros can be used. This is on 2016. I'm not an advanced Excel user and any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: A simple nested `VLOOKUP` should do it.  Please edit your question to show what you have tried.

Comment: If you prefer a more “flexible” rule than 1:1 matching, what is your requirement? Not sure, I understand your remark about duplicates and counting. If it relates to how to use the formula for all entries of table 1, probably you already know, you can just copy and paste the cell formula and Excel will adjust accordingly (e.g. for the vlookup, the matching criteria  as a relative cell reference of the current row with change accordingly and the absolute references to the arrays of the matching and returning columns remain unchanged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use Power Query. Perhaps this is what you want if you are working with 6000 rows.

You could set up your two input tables as Excel Tables, let's call them **tableType** and **tableProduct**.

> Click anywhere in the table and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>. Then in the **Table Design** tab, enter the names as above.

[image]

You can then go into the Power Query editor and use the script below to merge the two tables.

> **Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > Blank Query**

[image]

Then paste this script over the empty script that is written into the Advanced Editor.

```
let
   dimProduct = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tableProduct"]}[Content],
   dimType = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tableType"]}[Content],
   Source = Table.NestedJoin(dimProduct, {"Product"}, dimType, {"Product"}, "dimType", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
   #"Expanded tableType" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "dimType", {"Type"}, {"Type"}),
   #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded tableType",{"Product"}),
   #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Type", "Vendor"}),
   #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Type", type text}, {"Vendor", type text}})
in
   #"Changed Type"
```

Then Close and Load To and choose where you want your table to go. To update it, `Right-Click` and `Refresh`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mark fitzpatrick. Learnt something totally new today and I owe it to you :)

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to do that. `XLOOKUP()` may best fit.

```
=XLOOKUP(XLOOKUP(B10,$A$2:$A$6,$B$2:$B$6,""),$D$2:$D$6,$E$2:$E$6,"")
```

If you are on ***Excel-2016*** then can use `INDEX/MATCH` like-

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$6,MATCH(INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(B10,$A$2:$A$6,0)),$D$2:$D$6,0))
```

With `VLOOKUP()` can try-

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(B10,$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE),$D$2:$E$6,2,FALSE)
```

With most recent release of ***Microsoft-365*** can use `BYROW()` for one go.

```
=BYROW(B10:B14,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(XLOOKUP(x,A2:A6,B2:B6),D2:D6,E2:E6)))
```

And by `FILTER()` function.

```
=@FILTER($E$2:$E$6,$D$2:$D$6=FILTER($B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6=B10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Harun24hr, your solution works great too! However, I accepted the Power Query solution as it helps me solve similar issues in a more elegant way

Comment: @Arun No issue. You will accept better one.